# Array to an unordered list

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to map some arrays values to an unordered () list.

```
    <?php
            $files = scandir($dir);
            //remove "." and ".."
            print_r($files);
    ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
            <li><?= $file ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

It does iterate through the array correctly as it gives bullets for `<li>` elements. However no string output is seen next to those bullets. Also when I print_r the array the values are there.

The output looks like this with the correct number of bullets but no text next to them:

> .
>   .
>   .

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($files);`? Anonymize if you like.

Comment: If the output of `print_r($files);` gives null, it means you have a problem with your `$dir` variable. So check other sections of your code. You might have written the wrong name for the variable (e.g. could have been `$dirs`) or you could have forgot to initialize it, or you could have had an error beforehand, which only generated a warning.

Comment: I deleted the value of the "$dir" variable since it was not important for the answer. 

The output is something like 

Array ( [2] => commander.Command1.php [3] => commander.Command2.php [4] => commander.helloCommand3.php )

Comment: I can't give upratings yet (not enough reputation). Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: No worries. Ready to help anytime.

Comment: You should ask more useful questions. Then you get reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but this might work:

```
<?php
  $files = scandir($dir);
  //remove "." and ".."
  print_r($files);
?>

<ul>
  <?php foreach($files as $file) { ?>
  <li><?php echo $file; ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

That's what I would use, and if this doesn't work, it might be because your `$dir` variable contains nothing (has an error). One reason why your original code might not have worked, because I don't think the `<? ?>` tags are compatible on every server. Also, from what I know, there is no `<?=$var ?>` thing in php. I thought it only exists in ASP and the like.

**EDIT:** In answer to your question about the inferiority of curly braces, they are the commonly accepted standard in PHP. This might be different in the C/C++/C# Family, I don't know.

Comment: Also, using my method with the curly braces '{ & }' is easier, because in most code editors like Espresso, Coda, Smultron, jEdit, Notepad++, etc., they have a bracket detection system, which pairs up brackets. This feature will allow you to debug a bugged program. Therefore, you should use the curly braces. It's less code anyway. Saves a second every time you type it.

Comment: They say that using curly braces in PHP is the alternate way and should be avoided. It seems most natural to me (coming from C family languages) to use them, can you explain why it is frowned upon by some?

Comment: Who says? I never learnt to use the way which you use anyway. It really makes error-detecting difficult when you're not using curly braces, as they don't break up your code into sections. What text editor do you use?

Answer (score 6):

```
function array2ul($array) {
    $out = "<ul>";
    foreach($array as $key => $elem){
        if(!is_array($elem)){
            $out .= "<li><span>" . $key . ": " . $elem . "</span></li>";
        } else {
            $out .= "<li><span>" . $key . "</span>" . array2ul($elem) . "</li>";
        }
    }
    $out .= "</ul>";
    return $out; 
}
```

Comment: This is a good candidate for `sprintf()`, cleaning up the concatenation; same with using compound assignment (`$out .= "...";`). Also, mixing braced blocks (`if`) and non-braced blocks (`else`) is bad mojo.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
    <li><?php echo $file ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php foreach($files as $file): ?>
    <li><? echo $file ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `<?= $file ?>` with `<?php echo  $file ?>` or enable your sort tags by php.ini ; it seems your server has not it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Used this today:

```
if ( !empty($files) ) echo '<li>' . implode('<li>', $files);
```

Comment: A much more elegant solution. Thank you.