# PHP array to unordered list

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have hopefully a simple question that I cannot find any answers with my issue that are complete.

I have an array returned from MySQL that looks like this

```
mysql> select c.comment, d.name, m.ounces from drink d 
       inner join mix m on m.drinkID = d.ID
       inner join cocktail c on m.cocktailID = c.id
       where c.id =5;
+----------------------+------------+--------+
| comment              | name       | ounces |
+----------------------+------------+--------+
| Long Island Iced Tea | Vodka      |   0.75 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Gin        |   0.75 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Rum        |   0.75 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Tequila    |   0.75 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Sour Mix   |   2.00 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Cola       |   1.00 |
| Long Island Iced Tea | Triple Sec |   1.00 |
+----------------------+------------+--------+
```

I am trying to get PHP to generate a unordered list similar to this below.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>
      Long Island
    </h2>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li>0.5 oz Vodka</li>
        <li>0.5 oz Rum</li>
        <li>0.5 oz Gin</li>
        <li>0.5 oz Tequila</li>
        <li>0.5 oz Triple Sec</li>
        <li>1 oz Sweet and Sour Mix</li>
        <li>1 oz cola </li>
      </ul>
```

I was trying this:

```
    $ingredient = "select 
       c.comment, d.name, m.ounces 
       from drink d 
       inner join mix m on m.drinkID = d.ID
       inner join cocktail c on m.cocktailID = c.id 
       where c.id = 4";
    //print($ingredient);
    $result = mysql_query($ingredient);

<?php foreach($result as $results): ?>
    <li><? echo $results ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

from here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151690/array-to-an-unordered-list) but cannot figure out why I keep receiving HTTP 500 errors from PHP.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: typically 500 are syntax errors

Comment: Thank you. I was reusing code from another article. Can the mysqli_* functions just be found and replaced or are they very different?

Comment: Check your php open close tag inside li, and mysqli is very similar procedural. Object oriented looks a tad different but not much.

Comment: When you encounter and internal error you should check the log files to see what causes the error. Also check if you have the php short tag enabled.

Comment: @AlexHowansky. The old mysql api is one of the reasons people consider PHP a bad language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using short tags which a most likely disabled. Try this below

`<li><?= $results['ounces'] . ' oz  '. $results['name']?></li>`

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_query()` returns a set of rows, not an individual row

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
  <li> <?= $row['ounces'] ?> oz <?= $row['name'] ?></li>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Hopefully, mysql_query returns an error. Nothing more. Nothing less.

Comment: One would hopefully test for an error before looping over the results. I guess I should have added that